# Cant add and remove class when using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using the following plugin in my app: http://firedev.com/jquery.keynav/

my json file:

```
[
  {
    "appName": "Some name",
    "appDesc": "Some Description",
  },

  {
    "appName": "Other name",
    "appDesc": "Other Description",
  }
]
```

my html with angular:

```
<li ng-repeat="app in apps">
   <a class="selected" href="#">
     <p>{{app.appName}}</p>
     <span>{{app.appDesc}}</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

my html without angular:

```
<li>
  <a class="selected" href="#">
   <p>Some name</p>
   <span>Some Description</span>
 </a> 
</li> 
<li>
  <a class="" href="#">
   <p>Other name</p>
   <span>Other Description</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

**Issue:**
Angular shows the list items in my json file just fine. However it doesn't add/remove the "selected" class when doing it the angular way. When I use static html, it adds / removes the selected class. I tried adding the ng-repeat in the  and in a  tag before the list but still the same issue. I also tried adding "selected" ass class (as the first one is in the static html) but then all items get that class.

I would really appreciate it if someone with experience could help me with this really annoying issue.

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation you linked to says, just don't set the selected class at all. Then by default it will choose the first one for you.

```
<li ng-repeat="app in apps">
   <a href="#">
     <p>{{app.appName}}</p>
     <span>{{app.appDesc}}</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

---

Alternatively you could use `$first` to apply a class to only the first link.

```
<li ng-repeat="app in apps">
   <a href="#" ng-class='{selected:$first}'>
     <p>{{app.appName}}</p>
     <span>{{app.appDesc}}</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

---

**Third option**

I suspect that when you call `$('a').keynav();` the DOM has not yet been rendered.  To fix this you can use $timeout to delay your code until after the ng-repeat has run.

```
app.controller("myController", function($scope, $timeout){

    $scope.apps = 
    [
      {
        "appName": "Some name",
        "appDesc": "Some Description",
      },

      {
        "appName": "Other name",
        "appDesc": "Other Description",
      }
    ];

    $timeout(function () {
        $('#navigation a').keynav();
    })
})
```

I suppose if you wanted to be correct, because this is DOM manipulation you should encapsulate it inside a directive.  But I'll leave that up to you.

---

<sub>(By popular demand)</sub>
**Working example:**
https://jsbin.com/tejecizeqi/2/edit?html,css,js,output

The styles are a little funky and I had to copy in all the keynav library code.  *You can scroll to the bottom of the JS plane to see my code.*
I had to tweek the css a little to make it visible, but you probably don't need to on a real project.

*You need to click on the black plane first to give it focus*.  Again, in a real application this would not be necessary.

Comment: Update: 2nd alternative: This adds the class to the first alternative but it doesnt change when I navigate.

Comment: @Angelo, I tried to create a JSfiddle, but it wouldn't let me save it, like you said.  I could see the code did work though.

Comment: Thank you for your dedication trying to help! 3rd alternative: I got a syntax error when using $timeout but I tried with document.onload  and other solutions and it was still the same, didnt work using ng-repeat. I also tried switching place with the script.js and angular but no success so far.

Comment: You won't be able to use onload, because that will run too soon.  This code needs to be inside your controller, so that it runs as soon as angular has created the markup.  Did you remember to inject $timeout in your controller?  I will post the whole controller to be clear.

Comment: Ok, all the controller code is there now.  If you still get the syntax error, could you post it and more of the code you are using so maybe we can fix.  I am very close to 3000 points now, so I'm determined to get this selected answer  :)

Comment: Hi Buh Buh, thanks for the help! I did that and I get the appName and appDesc info in there and no errors now, but I still can't navigate through those that are using the ng-repeat :( Is there some other way I can bring them in using a json file (and not ng repeat) instead of using static html, that I can try? I know that they are highlighted because when I click "enter", their a href gets triggered. But they're not adding and removing the "selected" class which is really strange.

Comment: Buh buh! We're so close, dont give up now! :P

Comment: Ha ha :)   How is that version for you?  If it is good please don't forget to vote up and click the green selected answer tick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do not copy paste the code. Write the code yourself.

html doesn't support quotes  like this `”`. Replace all of them with `"`.

When you use `”`, then html attributes are invalid.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question properly, you are trying to add a class conditionally. You can do like below

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{selected: item.selected}">{{item.name}}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. You're correct and Im using this plugin  http://firedev.com/jquery.keynav/ to navigate with keys. However your solution didnt work for me. Maybe the "item.selected" part should be something else?

Comment: I tried but it doesnt work on jsfiddle because its using keystrokes to navigate

Comment: You can see the code for it here: https://github.com/firedev/jquery.keynav/blob/master/javascript/jquery.keynav.js maybe you recognize what condition to putt instead of item.selected?